# How to add a post-fix to a DOSKEY [CMD]

Tags: batch-file, cmd, doskey

I would like a prefix to run a command but slightly differently, for example

```
openlink (opens the link)
```

Then I would like to be able to say open it 2 times by using a prefix, for example

```
openlink *2 (opens the link twice)
```

I would like the number to be corresponding to the times opened Eg. openlink *7 would open the link 7 times.

Comment: That is a post-fix, not a prefix.   A prefix comes before, and would look like:  `2* openlink`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my bad english

Comment: In CMD, `doskey open=for /l %A in (1 1 $1) do start "" $2`. Use `%%A` instead of `%A`, if run from batch-file. Usage, `open 3 notepad` to open 3 notepads.

Comment: @michael_heath Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping your command (`openlink`) in a batch file that uses `set /A` to keep track of a count?

```
@echo off
SET /A CNT=%1
:l0
    openlink foo
    SET /A CNT=%cnt%-1
    IF NOT %cnt% == 0 GOTO l0
:end
```

Then, you could call it like `myopenlink.bat N` to call the command `openlink foo` N times.

Comment: Seems to just open the link repeatedly, forever

Comment: What exactly does `openlink` do when called standalone on the command line?

Comment: Sorry, probably "start chrome (link)" "start chrome" by its self just opens a new tab in chrome

Comment: @ClarenceHog If you have found that my answer has solved your problem, you are welcome to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Another questions if that is ok. Is it possible to run this as a command, like `video 3` using doskey?

Comment: @ClarenceHog Not entirely sure what you're asking there.

Comment: So `doskey` can be used to set a custom command. eg `doskey openyt=start chrome www.youtube.com` then if you ran `openyt` it would open up youtube. I would like that but have the post-fix on the end to open it up `x` many times. Eg `openyt 4` which would open youtube 4 times

Comment: @ClarenceHog As far as I'm aware, there isn't that functionality in doskey, hence why I proposed a solution of creating a batch file; just put it somewhere in your system's `%path%` and name it `openyt.bat` rather than creating a doskey macro and there will be no observable difference to you.